# Obfuscating data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to obfuscate data in SQL Server for development purposes to hide sensitive data without encryption keys because that's crack-able.

Comment: Are you referring to anonymising a tabular data or obfuscating procedural SQL e.g a stored procedure?

Comment: can developer see columns with sensitive data, while actual data are obfuscated, or entire columns need to be invisible?

Comment: the data will have sensitive information such as name and date of birth so would like to scramble the data with any nonsense random letters or numbers. So the developer could use the database but not exposed to sensitive information

Comment: any idea on how that could be achieved?

Comment: Manually encrypt / obfuscate your specific strings before storing them in the DB? On retrieval, have an algorithm / call that unscrambles them?

Comment: When will you actually use the sensitive data? will it come back via a is this obfuscated format?

Comment: You can create views without sensitive columns, and give developers permission to select a view, not a table. that may one way, not sofisticated, but can be helpful

Comment: well I will give you more details. I got the main protected server with the data and a development and testing server. I would like to be able to be able to transfer an obfuscated names and dob from the main server when I take a backup so when restored on the development server the data will already be scrambled or obfuscated

Comment: If you want to get the data back, then you're talking about encryption, which will by necessity have a key. If you just want to scramble the data around so that you can use it as a test database without your devs seeing sensitive info, you can simply replace the data with values from a random number generator, or sequential IDs. The database I'm working on currently is full of people called Mr A 1, Mrs B 2, Ms C 3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

OK I am not sure if you require the data to be encrypted for regulatory purposes or just because you don't trust your developers.  Given I don't know the laws where your data resides I can't answer the regulatory side of things.

For the trust side the best solution is not to encrypt/decrypt the data (although that may be needed for other reasons), but to partition data sets and only allow defined people to access their required data.  You do this by having separate development, staging and production environments:

1. The developers only work in the development environment which is loaded with enough dummy data for them to do their job.  Developers have full access to the data and code here.
2. QA people test the code in a staging environment which mimics the real system, but again only has enough dummy data loaded for the testing.  Developers may or may not have access to this system
3. The production environment has the tested code and all the real data.  Only trusted system admins have access to this system.  Developers do not have any access to this system.

The sensitive data is protected by the system admins granting the correct permission to roles that people play in maintaining the overall system.

At some point you need to trust someone with your data, but by partitioning it you can reduce the number of people who have access to it.

**Edit**

From a comment it seems that you already have this architecture, and that you want to transfer the live data from production server to the development server.  In general that is a `Bad Idea`, and defeats the purpose of having the split environment.

Unless you have some sort of compelling reason to do so, there should be no need to have actual sensitive data in the development environment.  If you want to do load testing etc then get some development people to code up data generation routines.